# Oracle package doesn't recognise all variables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, package

I have an Oracle express database set up at my home laptop for one university project. I've exported the database in a sql script and tried to import it on my workplace and everything works except the package. Package is created but Oracle does not seem to recognise all variables that are declared and he only recognises the first variable (see code below) and in my case that is `SIFRADOB NUMBER:=0;` My triggers are showing errors because they can't see the variables that are declared in the package. I have dropped the package and created it again and still got the same issue. I've even dropped the database but the issue has reappeared. And here is the image of the problem http://s17.postimg.org/67izq4wcf/package_error.png

```
    create or replace PACKAGE "PAKET" AS
    SIFRADOB NUMBER:=0;
    NAZIVDOB VARCHAR2(50);
    STARASIFRA NUMBER:=0;
    STARINAZIV VARCHAR2(50);
    SIFRAJM NUMBER:=0;
    NAZIVJM VARCHAR2(80);
    SIFRAPRO NUMBER:=0;
    BROJPOR NUMBER:=0;
    END;
```

Comment: Can you show the trigger?  A Trigger and a Package are 2 separate objects, and they normally cannot "see" each other. Now, the way you've declared these vars in the pkg, you should be able to reference them outside, via "paket.sifradob", etc .... so it might just be a privilege issue. I'm confused that you say the first one's ok. Can you show the results you're getting? the error, etc? I can't view that image from work, so you'll have to find another way to link to it. (I thought one could load images into their post here, no?)

Comment: SQL Developer looks exactly the same to me with a package spec with multiple variables (version 4.1.0). It doesn't affect the ability to refer to the other variables at all. Your trigger errors are likely to be completely unrelated to how SQL Developer looks; you really need to include your table DDL, trigger code and the error you get in the question.

Comment: Afaik oracle identifiers become case-sensitive when enclosed in double qoutes - do you refer to the package as `PAKET` (uppercase) in your trigger ?

Comment: Yes, I do refer with the uppercase letters in the trigger.

Comment: @collapsar, in Oracle `"PAKET"` is identical to `PAKET` and `paket`.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp That doesn't seem to be correct, see [these Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223). You cannot refer to `"PAKET"` without quotes or with different case.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the case. Try it with any all-uppercase identifier and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that issue is in some strange 'recognition'. As I understood, package was compiled without errors and can be recompiled, so it contents should be available.

First of all, I'd check if you used some non-latin characters. Identifiers, say, PACKET and РАСКЕТ are completely different in spite of looks equal. It may explain why you have РАСКЕТ.XYZ described but PACKET.XYZ could not be referenced.

Generally, once you even dropped database, you can start from empty schema. So please do it and execute with your package script like

```
create table T (...);

create package P
  x number;
  y number;
  z number;
end;
/

create trigger t_bi before insert on t
begin
  P.y := 1;
end;

show errors;
/
```

I doubt if it'll lead some errors but if so, please publish log of these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles and all variables are present just fine so it isn't that, its probably just SQL Developer or your permissions on the object aren't correct.
Verify that the code you compiled is loaded by executing:
`select text from user_source where name='PAKET';`
If you see all the variables listed in there then it is loaded properly.

Comment: Yes, this did list all my variables that were declared in the package.

Comment: Then they were all there. I like the below answer about possible non-latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

After working through all of the answers posted none solved the problem. I've eventually went to the triggers and just "renamed" so to say literally retyped word "PAKET" in my variables, compiled the triggers and it worked! Really awkward if we take into consideration that I basically haven't changed anything. Sometimes Oracle works in mysterious ways. :)